# create a tool that manages an equivalence relation that can be changed in a specific way by the program

Tags: c++, testing, equivalence

Whats going on:
So I've written a program that manages equivalence relations and it does not include a main. I'm supposed to test it in a separate file where I make an ER (equivalence relation), merge some things, and show the result.

What I need help with:
I'm not sure how to write up the testing file. I don't think I'm doing it right because it isn't working, but I don't know whats wrong. I'm not sure if I should just be running the function or using a print statement to show what it returns?

Code I'll be displaying:
I'll show equiv.h (which is code for a separate file I need to use and given to me by my professor), equiv.cpp (the code with all the functions in it that I've been working on and need to test), and the testequiv.cpp (the file I'm supposed to use to test each function) in that order.

equiv.h :

```
// These #ifndef and #define lines make it so that, if this file is
// read more than once by the compiler, its body is skipped on all
// but the first time it is read.

#ifndef EQUIV_H
#define EQUIV_H

// An equivalence relation is an array of integers.
// So ER abbreviates int*.  

typedef int* ER;

// Public functions

ER   newER      (const int n);
void destroyER  (ER R);
bool equivalent (ER R, const int x, const int y);
void merge      (ER R, const int x, const int y);

// The following is advertised here solely for debugging.  These must
// only be used for debugging.

void showER(const ER R, const int n);
int  leader(ER R, const int x);

#endif
```

equiv.cpp :

```
// This program is a tool that manages an equivalence relation that can be 
// changed in a specific way by the program


#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

// newER(n) returns an equivalence relation that can handle set {1, 2, …, n}.

int* newER(int n)
{
  int* R = new int[n];
  for(int i = 1; i < n; i++)
  {
    R[i] = i;
  }
  return R;
}

//showER(R, n) prints the entire contents of array R (of size n) in a 
//readable form for debugging.

void showER(int* R, int n)
{
  for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
  { 
    printf("%d",R[i]);
  }
  printf("\n");
}

//leader(R, x) returns the leader of x in equivalence relation R.

int leader(int* R,int x)
{
  if (R[x] == 0)
  {
    return x;
  }
  else
  {
    return leader(R, R[x]);
  }
}

//equivalent(R, x, y) returns true if x and y are currently in the same 
//equivalence class in equivalence relation R.

bool equivalent(int* R,int x,int y)
{
  if (leader(R, x) == leader(R, y))
  {
    return true;
  }
  else
  {
  return false;
  }
}

//merge(R, x, y) merges the equivalence classes of x and y in R.

void merge(int* R, int x, int y)
{
  if(!equivalent(R, x, y))
    {
        int xLeader = leader(R,x), yLeader = leader(R, y);
        R[xLeader] = yLeader;
    }
}

//destroyER(R) deallocates R.

int destroyER(int* R)
{
  delete R;
}


int main()
{
  return 0;
}
```

testequiv.cpp Set up to test the function newER:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include "equiv.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  newER(7);

  return 0;
}
```

NEW CODE!
So I have worked on this and my new codes are as follows:
equiv.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;
typedef int* ER;

// newER(n) returns an equivalence relation that can handle set {1, 2, …, n}.

ER newER(const int n)
{
  ER R = new int[n+1];

  int i;

  for(i=0; i<=n + 1; i++)
  {
    R[i]= i;
  }
    return R;
}

//showER(R, n) prints the entire contents of array R (of size n) in a 
//readable form for debugging.

void showER(const ER R, const int n)
{
  for (int i=1; i<=n; i++)
  { 
    printf("%d",R[i]);
  }
  printf("\n");
}

//leader(R, x) returns the leader of x in equivalence relation R.

int leader(ER R,const int x)
{
  if(R[x]==0)
  {
    return x;
  }
  if(R[x]==x)
  {
    return x;
  }
  else
  {
    return leader(R, R[x]);
  }
}

//equivalent(R, x, y) returns true if x and y are currently in the same 
//equivalence class in equivalence relation R.

bool equivalent(ER R,const int x,const int y)
{
  if (leader(R, x) == leader(R, y))
  {
    return true;
  }
  else
  {
  return false;
  }
}

//merge(R, x, y) merges the equivalence classes of x and y in R.

void merge(ER R,const int x,const int y)
{
  int x1, y1;
  if(!equivalent(R, x, y))
  {
    x1=leader(R,x);
    y1=leader(R,y);
    R[x1]=y1;
  }
}

//destroyER(R) deallocates R.

void destroyER(ER R)
{
  delete[] R;
}


int main()
{
  return 0;
}
```

**testequiv.cpp**

```
#include <cstdio>
#include "equiv.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
typedef int* ER;
int main()
{
   //Create new ER

     ER R = newER(7);

     //Display ER

     cout<<"Show ER:"<<endl;

     showER(R, 7);

     cout<<endl;

     //Call Function to merge

     merge(R, 1, 5);

     cout<<"\nER after merging 1 and 5:"<<endl;

     //Display ER after merging

     showER(R, 7);

     cout<<endl;

     //Call Function to merge

     merge(R, 2, 7);

     cout<<"\nER after merging 2 and 7:"<<endl;

     //Display ER after merge

     showER(R, 7);

     cout<<endl;

     //Call Function to test 1 and 5 are present in the same equivalence class

     bool ts1 = equivalent(R, 1, 5);

     //Check condition

     if( ts1)

     {

     //Print message

     cout<<"{1,5} is equivalence class"<<endl;

     }

     //If condition fails

     else

     //Print message

     cout<<"{1,5} does not form an equivalence class."<<endl;

     //Call Function to test 1 and 7 are present in the same equivalence class

     bool ts2 = equivalent(R, 1, 7);

     //Check condition

     if( ts2)

     {

     //Print message

     cout<<"1 and 7 are in the same equivalence class"<<endl;

     }

     else

     //Print message

     cout<<"1 and 7 are not in the same equivalence class."<<endl;

     //Call function to merge 5 and 7 in the same equivalence class

     merge(R, 5, 7);

     cout<<"\nER after merging 5 and 7:"<<endl;

     showER(R, 7);

     cout<<endl;

     //Call Function to test 2 and 5 are present in the same equivalence class

     ts1 = equivalent(R, 2, 5);

     //Check condition

     if( ts1)

     {

     //Print message

     cout<<"2 and 5 are present in the same equivalence class"<<endl;

     }

     else

     //Print message

     cout<<"2 and 5 are not present in the same equivalence class"<<endl;

     //Call Function to test 2 and 3 are present in the same equivalence class

     ts1 = equivalent(R, 2, 3);

     if( ts1)

     {

     //Print message

     cout<<"2 and 3 are present in the same equivalence class"<<endl;

     }

     else

     //Print message

     cout<<"2 and 3 are not present in the same equivalence class"<<endl;

     //Call function to merge 2 and 3

     merge(R, 2, 3);

     cout<<"\nER after merging 2 and 3:"<<endl;

     showER(R, 7);

     cout<<endl;

     //Call Function to test 3 and 7 are present in the same equivalence class

     ts1 = equivalent(R, 3, 7);

     //Check condition

     if( ts1)

     {

     //Print message

     cout<<"3 and 7 are present in the same equivalence class"<<endl;

     }

     else

     //Print message

     cout<<"3 and 7 are not present in the same equivalence class"<<endl;

     //Call Function to test 4 and 7 are present in the same equivalence class

     ts1 = equivalent(R, 4, 7);

     //Check condition

     if( ts1)

     {

     //Print message

     cout<<"4 and 7 are present in the same equivalence class"<<endl;

     }

     else

     //Print message

     cout<<"4 and 7 are not present in the same equivalence class"<<endl;

     //Call Function to merge 4 and 6 in the same equivalence class

     merge(R, 4, 6);

     cout<<"\nER after merging 4 and 6:"<<endl;

     showER(R, 7);

     cout<<endl;

     //Call function to merge 2 and 3 in the same equivalence class

     merge(R, 2, 3);

     cout<<"\nER after merging 2 and 3:"<<endl;

     showER(R, 7);

     cout<<endl;

     //pause window

    cin.get();

     //stop

  return 0;
}
```

Why is it saying stuff like: 
testequiv.cpp:(.text+0xe): undefined reference to `newER(int)'
testequiv.cpp:(.text+0x3f): undefined reference to`showER(int*, int)'

Comment: So far, so good, Now add some code to `tesetequiv` to "merge some things, and show the result".

Comment: I really don't understand what that means or how to do it. Which is what I'm asking to be explained.

Comment: `newER` leaves `R[0]` unassigned. `ShowER` accesses `R[n]` which is UB. `leader` seems to be an infinite loop. The code has too many problems to be discussed.

Comment: it is vitally important to develop new coding skills *in isolation* before you attempt to use them in combination. I can try to walk you through the writing of a test function before this question gets closed, if that would be helpful.

Comment: yes that would be wonderful! But I have actually written a lot for the tester but it won't compile and I can't figure out how to fix it so Ill add my new code to the post